# Slice is not working in python interpreter in udacity

Tags: python

I wrote this function in a challange using python for udacity:

```
example_input="John is connected to Bryant, Debra, Walter.\
John likes to play The Movie: The Game, The Legend of Corgi, Dinosaur Diner.\
Bryant is connected to Olive, Ollie, Freda, Mercedes.\
Bryant likes to play City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma, Super Mushroom Man.\
Mercedes is connected to Walter, Robin, Bryant.\
Mercedes likes to play The Legend of Corgi, Pirates in Java Island, Seahorse Adventures.\
Olive is connected to John, Ollie.\
Olive likes to play The Legend of Corgi, Starfleet Commander.\
Debra is connected to Walter, Levi, Jennie, Robin.\
Debra likes to play Seven Schemers, Pirates in Java Island, Dwarves and Swords.\
Walter is connected to John, Levi, Bryant.\
Walter likes to play Seahorse Adventures, Ninja Hamsters, Super Mushroom Man.\
Levi is connected to Ollie, John, Walter.\
Levi likes to play The Legend of Corgi, Seven Schemers, City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma.\
Ollie is connected to Mercedes, Freda, Bryant.\
Ollie likes to play Call of Arms, Dwarves and Swords, The Movie: The Game.\
Jennie is connected to Levi, John, Freda, Robin.\
Jennie likes to play Super Mushroom Man, Dinosaur Diner, Call of Arms.\
Robin is connected to Ollie.\
Robin likes to play Call of Arms, Dwarves and Swords.\
Freda is connected to Olive, John, Debra.\
Freda likes to play Starfleet Commander, Ninja Hamsters, Seahorse Adventures."def create_data_structure(string_input):
for x in string_input:
    if not ((ord(x)>60 and ord(x)<90) or x=="." or (ord(x)>97 and ord(x)<122)):
    string_input=string_input[:string_input.index(x)]+string_input[string_input.index(x):]
    network={}
    before=0
    string_input2=string_input
    while y < string_input.count('.')+1:
        network[y]=string_input2(0:before)
        string_input2=string_input2(:before-1)
        before=string_input2.find('.')
    return network,len(string_input),string_input
```

When I run the code the editor gives an error
message saying that the slicing is not working.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vm_main.py", line 33, in <module>
    import main
  File "/tmp/vmuser_igvmlwmdgu/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import studentMain
  File "/tmp/vmuser_igvmlwmdgu/studentMain.py", line 103
    network[y]=string_input2(0:11)
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could someone please tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Slice notation uses square-brackets...

Comment: You, my friend, need to look at the python syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax to slice the string/list/tuple in Python is `[:]` and not `(:)` i.e usage of *brackets* instead of *parenthesis*. Try:

```
string_input2[0:11]
```

For example:

```
>>> my_string = 'StackOverflow'
>>> my_string[5:9]
'Over'
```